# How to use segments in google analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, api, universal-analytics, analytics-api

In google analytics, We are able to create segments like below:

[image]

From the Google analytics API explorer, we can pull the segment information be it by segment id or by its code:

[image]

I would assume we can just cut and paste that code into the google analytics core reporting v3 reference code like we do with all the other parameters:

[image]

When I run the code however, i get this error:

```
    Arg, there was an API error : 400 : Invalid value 'users::condition::dateOfSession==2015-04-30;ga:sessionCount==1;condition::ga:campaign=@33100;sessions::condition::ga:userType=@Returning Visitor' 
for segment parameter.
```

Not sure whats wrong. When i use the segment id instead in my code for the segment parameter(segment ='gaid::xxxxxxx'), i get this error:

```
Arg, there was an API error : 400 : Segment XXXXXXXXXXX is not supported in the API.
```

Not sure how i should structure the code. Please help.